# How to define default value of one variable based on other variables in Terraform variable.tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-variables

For example, in variable.tf file we have this code:

```
variable "variable1" {
    type    = string
    default = "ABC"
}

variable "variable2" {
    type    = string
    default = "DEF"
}

variable "variable3" {
    type    = string
    default = "$var.variable1-$var.variable2"
}
```

Expected output:

```
variable3 = ABC-DEF
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I agree with @Montassar, you can use the [`local`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) block to create a new expression from the existing resources or the variables. But it should combine the variables like this:

```
locals {
  variable3 = "${var.variable1}-${var.variable2}"
}
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: yes thank you @Charles  you are right about the format of the output.
or also we can use variable3 = var.variable1+"-"+var.variable2 in HCL2 format.
I edited the answer thank you

Comment: Hi @MontassarBouagina 
i tried your solution, it throws an below error:

**An input variable with the name "variable3" has not been declared. This
variable can be declared with a variable "variable3" {} block.**

Comment: @Venki Please see the solution in my answer, it's the right one and will work for you!

Comment: @Venki i think you are using check if you are using  var.variable3 any where in your code   you should change it 
with local.variable3

Comment: @MontassarBouagina Thanks, yup it is working, can we place Custom Validation Rules for the local block which we place in variables i.e [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html)or how can we restrict the length to the variable3

Comment: @Venki yes you ca you can use validation within a variable  here's an exemple : 
variable "variable1" {
  type        = string
  description = ""

  validation {
    condition     = length(var.variable1) > 4  
   error_message = "The length should be > 4"
  }
}

and can you please validate the answer ty :)

Comment: @MontassarBouagina, ya for variable -validation is possible, what about local block?

Comment: @Venki no i don't think so any way you don't need a validation on a local since it's gonna be depending on the 2 orther variables so just validate you 2 variable and you ok to go

Comment: @Venki ty but why  u didn't validate my answer  ?

Answer (score 14):

You can use  `local` instead

```
locals {
  variable3 = var.variable1+"-"+var.variable2
}
```

and then instead of using `var.` use `local.` like this:

```
resource "example" "example" {

   example = local.variable3

}
```

ref : https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. [Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) clearly states:

> The default argument requires a **literal value** and **cannot reference** other objects in the configuration.

But you could probably use [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) for `variable3`.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge what you want is not doable with `default`.

However you can create `variable3` and just not assign it a default value and then in your call set `variable3 = var.variable1-var.variable2`

Not sure this solves your problem but to my knowledge the way you want to do it, won't work.

Also I would recommend upgrading to v0.12.

Comment: Hi @Berimbolinho , i tried with the above solution, it didn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the intended effect of the "default value" being that it is used only if the user did not provide a value - here is a more complete example:

```
variable "variable1" {
    type    = string
    default = "ABC"
}

variable "variable2" {
    type    = string
    default = "DEF"
}

variable "variable3" {
    type    = string
    default = ""
}    

locals {
    variable3 = var.variable3 == "" ? "$var.variable1-$var.variable2" : var.variable3
}
```